# woocommerce create subscription for user using functions / hooks provided

Tags: plugins

I have to create order with predefined "Free" product/subscription for existing user in word press. Need help with sample code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private function createWooComSubscription($user_id, $product_name, $total, $payment_id) {
        $arr = explode("-", $product_name);
        $product_title = trim($arr[0]);
        $product_subscription = trim($arr[1]);
        $product = $this->getWooComProduct($product_title);
        if ($product == null) {
            $this->getController()->log("Product not found ! woo com create subscription failed");
            return;
        }
        $variation = $this->getWooComVariation($product, $product_subscription);
        if ($variation == null) {
            $this->getController()->log("Variation not found ! woo com create subscription failed");
            return;
        }           
        // Create default order data
        $order_data = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_new_order_data', array(
            'post_type'     => 'shop_order',
            'post_title'    => sprintf( __( 'Order &ndash; %s', 'woocommerce' ), strftime( _x( '%b %d, %Y @ %I:%M %p', 'Order date parsed by strftime', 'woocommerce' ) ) ),
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'ping_status'   => 'closed',
            'post_excerpt'  => 'Internal order created',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_password' => uniqid( 'order_' )   // Protects the post just in case
        ) );

        // insert order, post
        $order_id = wp_insert_post( $order_data );
        if ( is_wp_error( $order_id ) ) {
                $this->getController()->log("unable to create order");
                return;
            }
        else
            do_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', $order_id );

        // Add line item
        $item_id = woocommerce_add_order_item( $order_id, array(
            'order_item_name'       => $product->get_title(),
            'order_item_type'       => 'line_item'
        ) );
        // product id, variation, quantity
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_product_id', $product->id );
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_variation_id', $variation['variation_id']);
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $variation['variation_attr_name'], $variation['variation_attr_name_value']);
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_qty', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_amount', 1 ) );

        // tax class
        foreach (array('_tax_class') as $nullkey) {
            woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $nullkey, '' );
        }
        // line item total values
        foreach (array('_line_tax', '_line_subtotal_tax', '_recurring_line_tax', '_recurring_line_subtotal_tax') as $zero_value_key) {
            woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $zero_value_key, woocommerce_format_total(0) );
        }

        // subscription data values
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "_subscription_interval", $variation['_subscription_period_interval'][0] );
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "_subscription_sign_up_fee", woocommerce_format_total( 0 ) );
        foreach (array('_subscription_length', '_subscription_period', '_subscription_trial_length', '_subscription_trial_period') as $sub_key) {
            woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $sub_key, $variation[$sub_key][0] );
        }

        // meta to find the order again !!!
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_myapi_payment_id',       $payment_id );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user',          $user_id );
        // other order data
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_key',              apply_filters('woocommerce_generate_order_key', uniqid('order_') ) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_currency',         get_woocommerce_currency() );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_prices_include_tax',     get_option( 'woocommerce_prices_include_tax' ) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_ip_address',    isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user_agent',    isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '' );          

        // order total values
        foreach (array('_order_shipping', '_order_discount', '_cart_discount', '_order_tax', '_order_shipping_tax', ) as $order_zero_key) {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, $order_zero_key, woocommerce_format_total(0));
        } 
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_total', woocommerce_format_total(0) );

        // Order status
        wp_set_object_terms( $order_id, 'pending', 'shop_order_status' );
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $post = get_post($order_id);
        WC_Subscriptions_Order::pre_process_shop_order_meta($post->ID, $post);
        $subscription_key = "{$order->id}_{$product->id}";
        WC_Subscriptions_Manager::create_pending_subscription_for_order($order, $product->id);
        WC_Subscriptions_Manager::activate_subscription(2, $subscription_key);
        WC_Subscriptions_Manager::process_subscription_payment(2, $subscription_key);
        foreach (array('_line_subtotal', '_line_total', '_recurring_line_subtotal', '_recurring_line_total') as $zero_value_key) {
            woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $zero_value_key, woocommerce_format_total($total) );
        }
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_total', woocommerce_format_total($total) );    
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_recurring_total', woocommerce_format_total($total) );
        WC_Subscriptions_Manager::set_next_payment_date($subscription_key, $user_id);
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta($item_id, "_subscription_recurring_amount", woocommerce_format_total($total));
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $order->update_status('completed');
    }

    private function getWooComProduct($product_title) {
        $find_args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'fields' => 'ids'
        );
        $posts = get_posts( $find_args );
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $product = get_product($post);
            if (sanitize_title($product->get_title()) == sanitize_title($product_title))
                return $product;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private function getWooComVariation($product, $subscription) {
        $attributes = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta( $product->id, '_product_attributes', true ) );
        $subscription_attr_slug;
        $subscription_attr_name;
        foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
            if ( isset( $value['is_variation'] ) && $value['is_variation']) {
                $subscription_attr_slug = $key;
                $subscription_attr_name = $value['name'];
                break;
            }
        }
        // Get variations
        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
            'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
            'order'         => 'asc',
            'post_parent'   => $product->id
        );
        $variations = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
            $variation_id           = absint( $variation->ID );
            $variation_post_status  = esc_attr( $variation->post_status );
            $variation_data         = get_post_meta( $variation_id );
            $variation_data['variation_id'] = $variation_id;
            $variation_data['variation_attr_name'] = $subscription_attr_name;
            $variation_data['variation_attr_name_value'] = $subscription;
            if ($variation_data['attribute_'.$subscription_attr_slug][0] == sanitize_title($subscription))
                return $variation_data;
        }           
        return null;
    }
```